# Can I assign eventlistener if the object is null?

Tags: c#, events, event-handling

I'm working on push notifications and have a `HttpNotificationChannel pushChannel` object.

In OnNavigatedTo i do a `pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += ...`

And in OnNavigatedFrom for my MainPage I have `pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived -= ...`

But can I do this whitout defining pushChannel? Like `pushChannel = HttpNotificationChannel.Find(channelName);` ?

Ofcourse it makes no sence, but I was curious if I can assign and deassign events like that

Comment: what is this trying to accomplish then?

Comment: did you try it? what happened? i doubt your computer exploded... explore a bit and then come back and post the results as an answer ;)

Comment: while pushChannel is null, can I still state pushChannel.HttpNotificationReceived += / -= ... ?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking here. If pushchannel is null when the code gets run, you get a null reference error.

Comment: I'm intrigued about how long you would estimate it would take you to actually put these lines of code into your program and run it. Mainly whether it is more or less than the time taken to ask the question on here... :)